# FFMPEG is losing connection when relay streaming with m3u8 to rtmp even with reconnection flag

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, hls

I'm trying to get streaming from mixer using api and relay to youtube rtmp

I did that but it is losing connection. it streams for almost 3 minutes and connection drops on server or local

commands tested:

```
ffmpeg -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey

ffmpeg -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc 


ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2 -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey


ffmpeg -re -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey


ffmpeg -timeout 3000 -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey


ffmpeg -re -i mixerstreamurl.m3u8 -c copy -bufsize 2000k -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -b 4000k -minrate 4000k -maxrate 4000k -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey


ffmpeg -i mixerurl.m3u8 -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 6000k -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 2 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 2000k -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey

ffmpeg -re -i mixerurl.m3u8 -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 6000k -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 2 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 2000k -f flv rtmp://youtubeurlandkey
```

No one of those commands worked